# FIR Filters: determining optimal number of taps and phase slope

Tags: filters, dsp-core, finite-impulse-response

As a design input for an low-pass FIR filter I have 6dB@1.6kHz, 24 dB/oct, sample frequency 48kHz. I need to specify phase response, and for that I need a phase slope. I have found, [from Julius O. Smith web page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Linear_Phase_Filters_Symmetric_Impulse.html), that the phase slope = (N-1)/2 where N is number of taps. What is the way to determine the optimal number of taps? I am aware of Kaiser formula, but I don't have ripple, passband and stopband frequencies that figure in the formula. I need the number of taps to calculate phase slope. Is there any other way to calculate, specify phase from my input requirements?

Comment: There is no formula, it's just trial and error (and experience). Also note that your specs are very minimalistic, e.g. what behavior do you expect in the pass band, etc.?

Comment: Please indicate if you are referring to a low-pass filter. Also, since you mention a constant group delay ("phase slope"), then another requirement should be phase linearity (not all FIR filters have linear phase).

Comment: That's the spec I have. There is a reference curve in Smaart v.7 and I am uploading coefficients to the filter so I can see how well it matches curve. Maybe the question how to find phase slope is good too. From Julius O. Smith site I have found that phase slope is (N-1)/2, N - number of taps.

Comment: For a linear phase filter, the group delay (phase slope) is indeed $(N-1)/2$, but the question is if linear phase is a requirement or not.

Comment: @MattL. Yes, linear phase is requirement.